# MySQL - How do I Calculate an Average Value Over a Period of Time When Only Value Changes are Recorded

Tags: mysql, timestamp, optimization, computed-column, query-performance

I am tracking the sales price of various items, and I would like to calculate the average price of each item over a period of time.

My simplified tables look like this:

```
Items
------------------
|key  | title    |
------------------
|1    | Sproket 1|
|2    | Sproket 2|
------------------
```

And

```
Prices
----------------------------------------
|item_key | price | datetime           |
----------------------------------------
|1        | 2.99  | 2014-11-25 02:05:56|
|1        | 1.99  | 2014-12-13 02:05:56|
|2        | 9.99  | 2014-10-25 02:05:56|
|2        | 8.99  | 2014-11-13 02:05:56|
----------------------------------------
```

The *Items* table contains a single row for each item.  The *Prices* table contains a single row for each price change.  The script runs daily and checks for the current prices, if the current price is different than the most recent item price recorded in *Prices* than a new entry is made in *Prices*.

My question is, **How do I calculate the average price of an item over 180 days?**

I can't use AVG because there is not a price entry each day for each item.

Comment: That is, you want the `AVG()` of the _last_ price for each day?

Comment: If a price was 40.0 for 60 days and 10.0 for the next 120 days, should the average be calculated as 20.0 or as 25.0 ?

Comment: If the price was $10.0 for 120 days and $40.0 60 days the average price should be: $20.00

Comment: I have decided it is just too messy to do in SQL with @variables.  Either have a price every day (as david suggests) or do the arithmetic in an application language.  (I deleted my "Answer" as being wrong and not salvageable.)

Comment: @RickJames, well, glad to know I didn't miss anything.  I suspected the answer might be "it can't be done."  Rick do you want to toss up a "it can't be done" answer that I can select as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I started to write SQL to do the task.  It got worse and worse.  I needed several @variables and perhaps 3 levels of subqueries.  So, I decided it was "impossible" in SQL, or at least very messy.

Instead, I would recommend either david's suggestion of having daily prices, which would make `AVG` work easily (probably no @variables or subqueries), or write it in some "real" programming language (PHP, VB, Java, ...).

One ugly was doing date arithmetic -- with bounds of 180 days ago and today.  Walking through the data `ASCENDING` led to one problem; `DESC` lead to a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

**KISS**

Assuming daily means every day including weekends and holidays.

1. Insert price for all items everyday
2. Use AVG() for value
3. Delete prices over 180 days.

Comment: Agree, that would be a simple solution.  But the number of rows in the table would increase dramatically, I don't know what the performance hit would be.  There are currently 20,000 items, and the prices are generally stable.

Comment: 20K items times 180 rows = 3.6M rows.  This is big, but manageable.  (1 billion is huge.)

Answer (score 0):

Your probably going to have to use group_concat function to aggregate by key so you can do math on those groups of values.

Comment: When you say do math on the group of values, you mean math outside of mysql?